# Get caret position coordinates relative to the window (x,y)

Tags: javascript, dom, caret

### Abstract

I would like to get the *window* position (in pixels) of the caret (when a user start typing).

### Full story

There's a multi-line `contentEditable` element with complex HTML structure inside of it.
When a user **start typing** anywhere inside it, on the first keystroke I would like to place an `absolute` positioned element below the caret. It is *imperative* that the newly added element will be injected into the `<body>` tag and **not** as a DOM node within the `contentEditable` element.

Therefor I require the exact global coordinates of the caret. I will be clear that there is **no** text selection.
 Selection is irrelevant here and even unlikely.

## My code

Normally a question should include some code the OP had tried & requires assistance with, but in this case I am all out of ideas. The [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) DOM event *does not* expose the coordinates. I will at least provide the end result of what I'm after:

```css
.info{
  border: 1px solid gold;
  padding: 8px;
  background: rgba(255,255,224, .8);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  max-width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<h2>contentEditable:</h2>
<div contentEditable>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    <strong>Ut enim ad minim veniam</strong>, 
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  </p>

  <p>
    Imagine the caret is somewhere here and the info element is right under it... <div>reprehenderit <em>in</em> voluptate</div> 
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt <small>mollit anim</small> 
    id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class='info' style='top:150px; left:60px;'>Extra info with a long list of some content goes here</div>
```

---

**Disclaimer:**

> I've done quite a bit of digging on the matter but unfortunately could not find an answer.
>   Some questions seem similar but looking deeper, they are not at all, and some are extremely old & obsolete

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more digging, I came about a [Gist file](https://gist.github.com/nothingismagick/642861242050c1d5f3f1cfa7bcd2b3fd) which did exactly what I wanted, 
so here is a working about which I've tweaked a bit:

```js
/**
 * Get the caret position, relative to the window 
 * @returns {object} left, top distance in pixels
 */
function getCaretGlobalPosition(){
    const r = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    const node = r.startContainer
    const offset = r.startOffset
    const pageOffset = {x:window.pageXOffset, y:window.pageYOffset}
    let rect,  r2;

    if (offset > 0) {
        r2 = document.createRange()
        r2.setStart(node, (offset - 1))
        r2.setEnd(node, offset)
        rect = r2.getBoundingClientRect()
        return { left:rect.right + pageOffset.x, top:rect.bottom + pageOffset.y }
    }
}

/////////////////[ DEMO ]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

const contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]')
const infoElm = document.querySelector('.info')

contenteditable.addEventListener('input', onInput)

function onInput(){
  const caretGlobalPosition = getCaretGlobalPosition()

  infoElm.style.cssText = `top:${caretGlobalPosition.top}px;
                           left:${caretGlobalPosition.left}px;`
}
```

```css
.info{
  border: 1px solid gold;
  padding: 8px;
  background: rgba(255,255,224, .8);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  max-width: 180px;
  display:none;
}

.info[style]{ display:block; }
```

```html
<h2>Place caret somewhere and type:</h2>
<div contenteditable>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    <strong>Ut enim ad minim veniam</strong>, 
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  </p>

  <h2>
    Imagine the caret is somewhere here and the info element is right under it... <div>reprehenderit <em>in</em> voluptate</div> 
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat f nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt <small>mollit anim</small> 
    id est laborum.
  </h2>
</div>
<div class='info'>Extra info with a long list of some content goes here</div>
```

---

Another solution which I've found: https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position